# How to set event listener to auto complete field in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing one application in that I am using Auto Complete Field in blackberry.
instead of string collection in demo e.g. I want to use vector collection.

Now I want to know that when I enter any value in that field it will me return result according to input. Now I want to take action when clicked by user on particular result out of 3/4 result returned by query. so how could it be possible?

Comment: Autocomplete field doesnt require any special field listener acc to my experience.When u start typing it automatically invokes search."Now i want to take action when clicked by user on particular result out of 3/4 result returned by querry."I didnt get what u meant by that.

Comment: as an e.g. u can take simple e.g. when u post question on this forum at that time when u are adding tag u enter B & it will return result like Blackberry,BlackberrySimulator etc.then u click on blackberry & that textfield for entering tag is filled with Blackberry.i.e particular action on particular result.I hope u understand my question now.

Answer (score 0):

try to run this code.I have worked on this having a db and filtering out names.
Make changes acc to ur need.Hope it helps.

```
      Try to run this code

        import java.util.Vector;
        import net.rim.device.api.collection.util.*;
        import net.rim.device.api.database.Cursor;
        import net.rim.device.api.database.Database;
        import net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseFactory;
        import net.rim.device.api.database.Row;
        import net.rim.device.api.database.Statement;
        import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
     import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
     import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;


  public class AutoCompleteFieldDemo extends UiApplication
   { 

       public static void main(String[] args)
      {

       AutoCompleteFieldDemo app = new AutoCompleteFieldDemo();
          app.enterEventDispatcher(); 
           }


  public AutoCompleteFieldDemo()
  {
     pushScreen(new AutoCompleteFieldDemoScreen());
    }


        public static String[] getDataFromDB()
         {
      Vector names = new Vector();

       try
        { 


    Database db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate("database1.db"); 
   Statement statement1 = db.createStatement("SELECT name FROM Directory_Items");
    statement1.prepare();
     statement1.execute();
    Cursor c = statement1.getCursor();
       Row r;

   while(c.next()) 
    {
 r = c.getRow();
  names.addElement(r.getString(0));

   }

statement1.close(); 
  db.close();

 }
catch( Exception e ) 
{ 
 System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
 e.printStackTrace();
   }

 String [] returnValues = new String[names.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
returnValues[i] = (String) names.elementAt(i);
 }

   return returnValues;

  }

  static final class AutoCompleteFieldDemoScreen extends MainScreen
  {



  AutoCompleteFieldDemoScreen()
  {


   BasicFilteredList filterLst = new BasicFilteredList();

     filterLst.addDataSet(1,getDataFromDB() ,"Names",BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
    AutoCompleteField autoFld = new AutoCompleteField(filterLst);
    add(autoFld); 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList)
{

```
 public void onSelect(Object selection, int type) {
     super.onSelect(selection, type);
     if(selection != null) {
         String selectionAsString = getEditField().getText();
         // Do whatever else you need to do with the String.
     }
 }
```

};